# JQuery - resolveWith --- Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function ... at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Trying to define a generic / vanilla - draggable function , . After Googling , i think i have isolated the issue to , Conflict within scripts ive included , am focusing on the `resolveWith`  within the error .

Function defined to create Draggable -li- list tags.

```
<script>
    $( function() {
          $( "#id_draggable" ).draggable();
                  } );
</script>
```

Initially missed including 2 scripts mentioned below ---

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Got error in Chrome Console `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function`

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function          jquery-3.3.1.js:3827 
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):2078)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.3.1.js:3534)
    at process (jquery-3.3.1.js:3602)
```

Having included the two scripts mentioned above - located them , exactly above the defined draggable function - again got error in Chrome Console

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (localhost/:2080)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)
```

Changed location of the included scripts - moved them to ,  within the -head tags . Again got error in Chrome Console -

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):2079)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)
```

Again Changed location of the included scripts - moved them to end of page just before ,page body closing TAG . Yet again got error in Chrome Console -

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):2078)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.3.1.js:3534)
    at process (jquery-3.3.1.js:3602)
```

**EDIT - 1** Removed ,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

which was one of the one of the included scripts . Let the other script which is

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

, remain at the bottom  of the page at the page body closing TAG. The error changes to as seen below -

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).draggable is not a function TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function   jquery-3.3.1.js:3818 
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8001/dc/eda_action/bhanu1aaccbhanu11aacc25/:2078:56)
    at mightThrow (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:3534:29)
    at process (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:3602:12) undefined
jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3818
process @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3606

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function      jquery-3.3.1.js:3827 
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):2078)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.3.1.js:3534)
    at process (jquery-3.3.1.js:3602)
(anonymous) @ (index):2078
mightThrow @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3534
process @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3602
```

Note that the earlier error trace did not have -

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).draggable is not a function TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
```

**EDIT-2** Seems i need to remove all instances of JQuery and JQuery UI as suggested here = https://wordpress.org/support/topic/receiving-javascript-error-stickthis-is-not-a-function/ , the error as of now is shown below ...

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).draggable is not a function TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function      jquery-3.3.1.js:3818 
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/dc/eda_action/bhanu1aaccbhanu11aacc25/:2103:42)
    at mightThrow (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:3534:29)
    at process (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:3602:12) undefined

jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3818

process @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3606
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with code for draggable LI list tags being within a Modal as of now moved out of Modal - all good now . Will at a later date again try with jQuery Draggable LI list tags within a Modal and report back here .